# How do I 'fill up' remainder of a size at compile time?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following

```
struct MyType { long a, b, c; char buffer[remainder] }
```

I wanted to do something like

```
char buffer[4096 - offsetof(MyType, buffer)]
```

But it appears that it's illegal

Comment: What is your reason for having `sizeof(MyType)==4096`?

Comment: Note that even if your second snippet "worked", there would still be no guarantee that `sizeof(MyType) == 4096` since the compiler may add additional padding for alignment purposes.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Eugene I have a pool of 4K and 64K memory and I do placement new on them

Comment: @Brian shouldn't the offset know that? It doesn't work so it doesn't matter. Also I use the alignment attribute but I dont think its standard.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie are you implying I don't actually want to do this? I have 4K memory pools that I do placement new on. My temporary workaround is 4096 - 24

Comment: From the little information in the original question, it is not clear why you want to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
struct ABC {long a,b,c; }
struct MyType : ABC {char buffer[4096-sizeof(ABC)];};
static_assert(sizeof(MyType)==4096,"!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem stems from trying to use the not-yet-fully-defined `MyType` type *while defining it.* You *could* do this with a union:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyType {
    union {
        struct { long a, b, c; } data;
        char buffer[4096];
    };
};
static_assert(sizeof(MyType) == 4096, "MyType size should be exactly 4K");

int main() {
    MyType x;
    x.data.a = 42;
    std::cout << sizeof(x) << " " << x.data.a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output (on my system):

```
4096 42
```

Because it's a union, the type actually holds the `a/b/c` tuple and `buffer` area in an overlapped region of memory, big enough to hold the larger of the two. So, unless your `long` variable are *really* wide, that will be the 4K buffer area :-)

In any case, that size requirement is checked by the `static_assert`.

That *may* be less than ideal as `buffer` takes up the entire 4K. If instead you want to ensure that `buffer` is only the *rest* of the structure (after the `long` variables), you can use the following:

```
struct MyType {
    long a, b, c;
    char buffer[4096 - 3 * sizeof(long)];
};
```

and ensure that you use `x.something` rather than `x.data.something` when accessing the `a`, `b`, or `c` variables.

This solves your problem by using the size of three longs (these *are* fully defined) instead of the size of something not yet defined. It's still a good idea to keep the `static_assert` to ensure overall size is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the compiler has total control over padding and layout. A union/struct combo combined with a `static_assert` sanity check might be enough for government work, but `std::aligned_storage` is also there to give you memory blocks that are safe to put objects in.

```cpp
struct MyType {
    long a, b, c;
};
using MyTypeStorage = std::aligned_storage<4096, std::alignment_of<MyType>::value>::type;

/* ... */

MyTypeStorage myTypeStorage;
MyType* x = new (&myTypeStorage) MyType {};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/87e7Tc

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. How do I accessing the bytes after C? I want a byte array/pointer

Comment: @Pac in this example, you can use `char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(x+1);` or `char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(x)+sizeof(*x);`